# Javascript Lint Error

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a small script in JS that is giving me annoying errors that I cannot spot.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('frontend')
    .config(config);
  config.$inject = ['$logProvider'];
  function config($logProvider) {
    // Enable log
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
  }
})();
```

They are related to code style with the functions:

```
  2:10  error  Missing space before function parentheses  space-before-function-paren
  9:1   error  Block must not be padded by blank lines    padded-blocks
```

Can anyone help me see what space is the error referring to?

Comment: is line 2 the line with `'use strict';`?

Comment: Hello. Yes, that is line 2

Comment: Is line 9  the comment? Try removing it?

Comment: Nope the same error appears. I would be ok if these code style errors could be ignored, is that possible with the linter and gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is flagging this line:

```
function config($logProvider) {
```

Your linter settings indicate that you need a space between function name and the parenthesis with the arguments, here is correct spacing:

```
function config ($logProvider) {
```

The second error indicates that you cannot have empty/commented lines as the first or last line in your blocks, which is triggered by this line:

```
// Enable log
```

Delete that comment, or add the comment to end of line in question:

```
$logProvider.debugEnabled(true); // Enable log
```